# Protractor test works on Firefox but fails on Chrome

Tags: javascript, windows, ubuntu, protractor, automated-tests

While i am using protractor with firefox (ubuntu) 46 all my test are green but when i use chrome some of them fails becouse command `browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,10000);');` doesn't work properly. I was trying to use :

`var elm = element(by.sth)
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elm.getWebElement());`

or

`scrollIntoView : function(){ arguments[0].scrollIntoView(); }`

but they didn't work aswell.

And my second question is, when i try to start the same test on Windows they all fail becouse of missing locators etc. is it becouse of archtecture differences of browseres or my tests aren't writen well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved problem.
Problem was with promises, We must treat `browser.executeScript('window.scroll(0,600);')` as a promise so if the test is too fast ,it fails.
Solution is using :

```
browser.executeScript('window.scroll(0,600);').then(function(){
    return this;
});
```

It also fix problem with missing locators, becouse the have time to load on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to use scrollIntoView ? I have scrollbars in the app I test, but Protractor scrolls automatically when needed.

Otherwise it would be helpful to have more details about the failure. What error message do you get? In what context is called your function? An extract of your code could help.

Comment: Never mind i handel my first problem with
```var sgpt = require('sg-protractor-tools');```
```sgpt.scroll.scrollTo(element);
```
but still got problem to start this test on windows :)